# Cfile idempotentRepository Bean using a registered bean

Tags: idempotent, cfile

when using a cFile start point, the use of Spring beans declared at design time work fine for declaring the Fileidempotent repository that I wish to create.

But I want to have the bean configured at Runtime or at design time but soft-coded with parameters.

So I created a bean that is as follows:

public class FileIdempotentRepository(File fileStore,int cacheSize,long maxFileStoreSize){

```
          try{
                this.start;
                System.out.println(this.getStatus());
          }catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

This bean is registered under the Id  "test1" in the beanRegister.and the 3 arguments passed in.

in cFile I declare parameter idempotentRepository as "#test1"

the bean starts and has a running status . The  cFile does not see this repository using that parameter argument

Any help would be approeciated

Tony Pearson

I tried instantiating the bean directly from the parameter line thinking the instantiation thru a method would work versus the constructor but that failed.

I did expect the reference to the bean thru cFile to work

Comment: The bean code I typed in is incomplete it is missing the constructor before the try block

Comment: bean code is:   public class FileIdempotentRepository extends ServiceSupport implements IdempotentRepository<String>         public FileIdempotentRepository(File fileStore,int cacheSize, long maxFileStoreSize){ try{ this.start();} }  etc